# Does Heartbleed Bug in OpenSSL affect ALL SSL certs

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, https, heartbleed

Does the Heartbleed Bug in OpenSSL affect ALL SSL certs, regardless of where I purchased or if I self-cert?

For example, if I bought an SSL certificate from GoDaddy and set this up on my server following their Apache tutorial (http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5238/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache), is this vulnerable to being exploited via Heartbleed?

Comment: If the certificate was used in a situation where it was used before OpenSSL was patched then consider the certificate to be useless and revoke it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug has no relation to certificates themselves. The bug is in the implementation of OpenSSL library, which makes it possible for malicious attacker to retrieve the private key of the server and other confidential information.

With the private key, the attacker can impersonate your web site, and possibly eavesdrop the traffic between your server and the client

So, if your server had a vulnerable version of the OpenSSL library, your private key might have been leaked and it is safest to regenerate the private key and get new corresponding certificates.

Comment: So, assuming one had a vulnerable version of OpenSSL previously and bought a cert from GoDaddy, the ideal method of re-securing one's server would be to install the updated version of Open SSL, then resign & reinstall the certificate?

Comment: Yes, regenerating the private key and getting a corresponding certificate is the safest thing to do after fixing the vulnerability.

Comment: Yes; revoke the current certificate the issue a new one

Comment: Revocation is also key step.  Without revocation, if an attacker has attacked your server, he can continue to use the cert he stole to impersonate your site.